# Does chopping up big pictures into smaller ones increase web speed performance?

Tags: html, performance

Checking the C&A website I noticed that they chunked their bigger pictures into little parts, which they positioned absolutely to make a big one out of it again.

Why are they doing this? Performance? One might be reasoning that loading 6 small pictures in parallel might be faster than loading one big picture at once. But is that actually the case? Wouldn't it just mean 6x as many requests where each of it utilizes 1/6th of the available bandwidth.

You can find an example [here](http://www.c-and-a.com/de/de/shop/product.html#!/Boys) (the picture of the two boys).

Comment: I'm guessing that they split the image to have multiple links on it...for calls to action and stuff. I can't see any performance improvement in having more requests.

Comment: I would say no - which is why we have sprites instead of many small images. One reason though would be for ipads and other such devices - they have a maximum image size they can use - I found this out when trying to use a massive background png and had to write a non desktop hack to use a chopped up picture

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source code you will see that different parts of the picture go to different sub pages like jeans or tee's...

I'm pretty sure they don't know what image mapping is lol... so, no chopping them up will not increase web performance.

Comment: as far as i can tell, there are only two links, but six images; that explanation alone does not make any sense at all. but yeah, it will not increase performance.

Comment: My explanation makes no sense xD? Well, I guess as long as I understand it it's fine lol.
How bout this, when you see visit a website and it has one big image, sometimes it will load a couple lines of pixels at a time, starting from the top. However, in this case you see one smaller picture load a a time. So, chopping them up does not help performance.

Comment: That is not what I wanted to say, what I wanted to say is: there's two links, but the picture is chopped into six images. So that cannot really be the reason they chopped it up(at leat I hope so).